# How to remove popups from Jenkins buildserver GUI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm managing multiple Jenkins buildservers and find that the "popups" that appear in the GUI when I move my mouse over elements are very annoying and cumbersome.

Here is an example of how the context menu hides the links to the other jobs when my mouse hover over the "Build printer software" job:

[image: context menu hides other jobs]

Is there a way to disable these popup menus?

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of those popups? I never encounter this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?
Otherwise, which popups (tooltips?) are you referring to?
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13995

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. So it's gone in 1.514? I'll see if I can upgrade to that and get rid of those hover-over-context menus. I'll mark this as "answered" if that does the trick.

Comment: Popups are gone in newer builds of Jenkins. Marked as "answered"